# Mongoose how do I query for multiple documents, save if not found, and return id?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to create a query to satisfy the following conditions:

1. Search for the documents with specified name's' in a collection.
2. If the documents with specified names do not exist in the collection, create new documents.
3. Return ._id of the documents either they are newly saved or not.

How can I achieve this without using a for loop?

```
var tagArr = req.body.tags.join()

Tag.find({tagName: {$in: tagArr}}, function(err, docs){
    // find the tag._ids by tagNames
    // if tag not found, create a tag
    // return old and new tag_ids with the tagNames
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [findOneAndUpdate()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate) with `upsert` option set to `true`:

```
var tagArr = req.body.tags.join();
var idArr = [];

tagArr.forEach(function(tag){
    Tag.findOneAndUpdate(
        {tagName: tag}, 
        {tagName: tag}, 
        {upsert: true}, 
        function(err, doc){
            if(!err)
            idArr.push(doc._id);
    }
});
```

If there is no tag with specified name, findOneAndUpdate() will create new one with that name and return it, so you can have its _id.